# How can I use SSL with a node-mysql pooled connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl

I'm using node-mysql by felixge to make database connections via Node.JS. I'm making lots of connections, so I thought it would be a good idea to use a connection pool:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

function createPool() {
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
        dateStrings : true,
        host : '***',
        user : '***',
        password : '***',
        database : '***'
    });
    return pool;
}
```

However, while node-mysql makes it very simple to use SSL for a normal connection:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  ssl  : {
    ca : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/mysql-ca.crt')
  }
});
```

It doesn't seem to show in the documentation that the SSL options are available when utilizing a connection pool.

**How can I use SSL with a node-mysql pooled connection?** or rather, can it be done at all?

Answer (score 3):

I re-read the docs and noticed this line:

> Pools accept all the same options as a connection.

Sorry about that. Anyway, the answer is that it accepts the same options as a normal connection.

Answer (score 2):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

function createPool() {
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
        dateStrings : true,
        host : '***',
        user : '***',
        password : '***',
        database : '***',
        ssl  : {
            ca : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/mysql-ca.crt')
        }
    });
    return pool;
}
```